# Angular 7 and jQuery datatable trigger event

Tags: datatables, angular7

I am new to angular 7 and want to implement datatable in angular 7.
I displayed data from api, and I triggered event from the table cell.
now I want to get data from the cell. but I get the data is null.

This is a component to display data from rest api.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getMeterReading().subscribe(tourData => {
        this.dtOptions = {
          bLengthChange : false,
          bInfo: false,
          data: tourData,
          columns: [
              {
                title: 'Unit',
                data: 'UnitID'
              },
              {
                title: 'Latitude',
                data: 'DeviceID'
              },
              {
                title: 'Logitude',
                data: 'DeviceID'
              },
              {
                title: 'Remarks',
                data: 'DeviceID'
              },
              {
                title: 'Image',
                data: 'Image',
                render: (data) => {
                  return data ? `<i class="fa fa-picture-o ImageMeterReading" data-blob="${data.data}" aria-hidden="true"></i>` : '';
                }
              }
          ]
        };

        $(document).on('click', 'i.ImageMeterReading', ($event) => {
          let blob = $($event).data('blob');
        });

        this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
        this.dataTable.DataTable(this.dtOptions);
        this.loading = false;
    }
}
```

I expect to get BLOB data from the table cell.
but the actual output is null now.

Comment: jQuery and Angular do not mix. Take a look at my library Easy Angular, the table component is very easy to use. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez and a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npn1p1

Comment: I installed the plugin and checked it. Fantastic!
Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Comment: I have one question. How can I customize the plugin? for example, If I want to remove paging etc..., then what should I do? and Do not have search option there?

Comment: Then don't put the paging and search options in. The pageSize attribute on the table sets the page size so leave it out, <ez-table-search></ez-table-search> adds the search option so don't add it, <ez-table-pager footer></ez-table-pager> puts a pager control in the footer so don't add it.